# Partial sum lookup / partial sum set assignment

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math

I have following problem to solve. As as input i have 2 decimal arrays. Sum of elements of both of them is equal. Actuall problem is to assign values from one array to second one by partial sums - if some element from one array is a sum of any number of elements from second array - they should be assigned to each other.

Sample1:

Array1: 25.0, 25.0, 50.0, 50.0
Array2: 50.0, 100.0

Expected result: 50.0 is sum of 25.0 and 25.0, 100.0 is a sum of 50.0 and 50.0
(0->0,1; 1->2,3)

Sample2:

Array1: 20.0, 70.0, 80.0, 130.0
Array2: 100.0, 200.0

Expected result:
100 = 20+80, 200 = 70+130   (0->0,2; 1->1,3)

Idea is to return assigned array element indexes and return as less assingments as possible.

Comment: Are you aware that this problem is NP-complete (e.g.: via Subset Sum)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

Unfortunately this is NP-complete, meaning you have to check all possible combinations.

However, if your problem is only has a small quantity of partial sums (such as your examples) then brute force away.

---

Moron is correct, not all NP-complete problem require checking all possible combinations.
However I believe [subset sum is one that does](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Exponential_time_algorithm).

Comment: "Unfortunately this is NP-complete, _meaning you have to check all possible combinations_" .False.

Comment: You have only managed to make your case weaker by including that link! According to that, you only check in the order of sqrt(M) where M is the total combinations. (2^(N/2) vs 2^N).